# Is this actually ごぬんくださーい, and does it mean "Excuse us!"?

Tags: translation

Is this actually ごぬんくださーい, and does it mean "Excuse us!"?

[image]

I got "Excuse Us!" from the English translation of the uncropped version of that image.

Comment: You seem to have misread め as ぬ.

Comment: @Sjiveru - Yes. Yes I did, *facepalm* If I caught that, this question wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's ごめんくださーい, not ごぬんくださーい. The actual phrase is just ごめんください, but here it's written with an elongation to reflect how people often pronounce it. In any case, 'excuse us' isn't quite an accurate translation; it's what you say when you enter someone's home without permission. Other options include 失礼（いた）します and お邪魔（いた）します. There's also an old-fashioned use before you leave, similar again to （お先に）失礼（いた）します.

Comment: Awesome answer, but I didn't know JAMA was spelled 邪魔! =)